# pegar campos separados na planilha excel com php

Tags: php

boa tarde.
minha duvida é a seguinte, tenho uma tabela no excel onde as celular a2, b2 a3, b3, c3,d3,e3 tem informações q gostaria de colocar em uma base de dados, como faço para pegar celular especificas em uma tabela do excel para preenche uma base de dados?
desde ja agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: tenho uma tabela no excel onde as celulas a3,b3, a5,b5,c5 e b7 tem informações q preciso colocar em uma base de dados mysql.